# How to generate typings for CSS modules with Parcel?

Tags: javascript, css, typescript, css-modules, parcel

I'm very new to Parcel. So this might seem like a dumb question to ask.

I have a project that uses typescript, react, less, parcel. And I need a way to generate typings since typescript is giving me the 'Cannot find module '`xxx`' or its corresponding type declarations.' error. I know I can create a global typing file for all modules ending with the extension `.less`, but that way I get errors 'Property '`xxx`' does not exist on type 'typeof import("*.less")'' and no IntelliSense when editing.

I'm not sure if this is even supposed to be handled by Parcel, I found an extension for VSCode [CSS Modules Typed](https://github.com/awwit/vscode-typed-css-modules) which seems to do the trick, but there are a few plugins for parcel which promise to do the same thing but I can't get them to work.

Answer (score 0):

Create a type declaration file (`.d.ts`) anywhere in your file tree with the following content:

`css.d.ts`

```
declare module "*.css" {}
```